# how to add multiple text which can be editable on canvas in android ?

Tags: android, canvas, arraylist, android-edittext

here i want to add Edittext alert dialogbox from where i can add multiple text on canvas in android . how to store edittext in array?

```
 if (c.getImage() == 3) {
        // canvas.rotate(45);
        mPaint.setTextSize(37);
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        canvas.drawText(c.getEdittext(),xTouch1, yTouch1, mPaint);


        // canvas.drawText("Hello",40,180,mPaint);

    }
        else if (c.getImage() == 3) {


        editTexts.add(new EditText(c.getEdittext(),xTouch1,yTouch1,mPaint));
        canvas.drawText(c.getEdittext(),xTouch1, yTouch1, mPaint);

        for (EditText l : editTexts) {

            canvas.drawText(c.getEdittext(), xTouch1, yTouch1, mPaint);

        }
        }
        c.setImage(0);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

i found answer how to add multiple text on canvas

```
class etext {
    float startX, startY, stopX, stopY;
    String etext1;

    public etext(String etext1, float startx, float stopY) {
        this.etext1 = etext1;
        this.startX = startx;
        this.stopY = stopY;

    }
```

make a perticular class for EditText and after that `

```
if (c.getImage() == 3) {

        mPaint.setTextSize(37);
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        //  canvas.drawText(c.getEdittext(),xTouch1, yTouch1, mPaint);
        canvas.drawText(c.getEdittext(), xTouch1, yTouch1, mPaint);
        editTexts.add(new etext(c.getEdittext().toString(), xTouch1, yTouch1));

    }
```

`